# Frontend application displaing progress from API

Tags: django, angular, websocket, server-sent-events

I've got a case where I have got 3 docker containers:
- frontend in Angular
- backend in Django
- processing API in python.

The use-case is that user sends a file to backend volume (using frontend GUI) and then API processes it. Processing takes some time, so API sends updates using SSE to the backend (which was a trigger for that action) and I would like to forward that progress updates to the frontend.

I've tried to use WebSockets for that (frontend <-- WebSocket --> backend <-- SSE --> API), but there is a lot of bugs in case of processing multiple files at once.

I also would not like to expose API to frontend. API can process multiple files in parallel.

Do You guys have got some best practices for such case?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.

One would be to use the WebSocket approach that you are already using, and figure out what the bug is and fix it.

The other would be to have the client (Angular app) poll the backend for status until it finishes.

The two approaches are fairly equivalent, except that the WebSocket would probably be a little less chatty, and would notify immediately when the processing is complete, instead of making the client wait for the next polling interval.

The WebSocket approach is nicer for the user and lighter on network traffic,
but the polling approach doesn't introduce the extra complexity of setting up and maintaining WebSockets on the front-end and back-end.